# Finding limits of functions by considering factorizations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

I had a go at these and ended up writing way too much.
Would a quicker way be to find the limits by considering factorizations in this case?

[image]

Comment: To be completely honest, it depends on (1) how long it takes you to find "the right factorization" (it gets better with practice; and (2) whether you value more time (to find the proof) and space (to write the proof). (the second quantity does not really get better with time.)

Comment: Do you know the derivatives of basic functions? If so, the answers are easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

a) Write $x^4-1$ as $(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)$.

b) Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1+2x}+\sqrt{1-3x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Beside factorization (when you can), multiplication by the conjugate (when it is feasible), L'Hospital rule, there is (what I do prefer) : Taylor series.

Considering the first case $$\frac{x^4-1}{x-1}=\frac{(1+y)^4-1}{y}$$ and using the generalized binomial theorem $$(1+y)^a \simeq 1+a y$$ you find for the first limit the value of $4$.

Doing the same for the second case $$\sqrt{1+2x}\simeq 1+x$$ $$\sqrt{1-3x}\simeq 1-\frac 32 x$$ $$\sqrt{1+2x}-\sqrt{1-3x}\simeq (1+x)-(1-\frac 32 x)=\frac 52 x$$

Comment: A great method, thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome ! Taylor series are extremely useful. If you don't know tham yet, pay a lot of attention when you will be teached abou them. For me, it is **the** key for almost all problems of limits.

Comment: We haven't done them rigorously yet but it should be done in a few weeks time. I will learn them properly, thanks again.